# Annotation on an expression

Tags: java, annotations

In Java you can add an annotation to a local variable, however, is it possible to put an annotation on an expression? *(I assume the answer is no, but thought I'd ask anyway)* I made a best guess of what it might look like, but it does not compile.

```
@interface Foo {}

class Bar {
    void bar() {
        // local variable annotation
        @Foo int i = 123 + 456;
        // expression annotation
        // error: illegal start of expression
        int j = 123 + @Foo 456;
        // error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
        int j = 123 + (@Foo int) 456;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would it be useful for, if you could do it?

Comment: @Sam something like [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) which lets you inject code based on annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See JLS [§9.6.4.1 @Target](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1):

> Annotation types may be applicable in *declaration contexts*, where annotations apply to declarations, or in *type contexts*, where annotations apply to types used in declarations and expressions.

`456` is an integer literal, not a *declaration* or a *type*, so it cannot be annotated.

Comment: Makes sense. To get the desired functionality I guess you would have to declare the expression as a local before using it; `@Foo int k = 456; int i = 123 + k;`

Comment: Actually, could you update the answer to include why `int i = (@Foo int)123;` is also not possible? `error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration`

Comment: `int i = (@Foo int)123;` is allowed if you declared the annotation like this: `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE) @interface Foo {}`